# Is there a verbose_name-like setting for Django's admin permission name

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In every Django admin, the permission is list in the following format.

**app_name|model_name|permission_name**

I wanna i18n or at least set these in my language.

So I go ahead and set the LANGUAGE_CODE in the settings.py at first.

But that's not enough, how can I fully customise it.

I'm using python3.4 and Django1.7.1

I realised that ***verbose_name*** and ***verbose_name_plural*** might be helpful and I do set these two attribute in all of my models. But for some reasons, some of them displayed and some of them don't.

Is this related to the **makemigration** and **mirgate** command, cause sometimes I added these two attributes after I done this.

Any way, need some help here.